Error after converting field type from number to text
I have a requirement where I converted the field from number to text since I do not want the number formatting on this field. After the conversion, I am getting the below error when trying to update value on this field. How can this be resolved?
Value for field 'EMPUID__c' in object 'My_Custom_Object__c' with data type 'STRING' should be a String but instead is a BigDecimal.

Example:
When the field was number data type, the value was something like 21,534. Since I do not want the comma, I changed the data type to text to have a value of 21534. Is there a way to remove the comma without changing the data type?

Formula fields are your friends

The Salesforce UI always displays Number type with commas.  Generally you should keep numeric data typed as Number, especially if you need to do calculations.  As mentioned by identigral, if you need to display it without commas, you should create a formula field.

I converted a number field to text as well and ran into this issue.  Then I deleted the field altogether and created a new field of the data type 'text' and still ran into the error.  I am trying to track the year of a vehicle, so I did not want the comma showing.  A formula field would be possible but not as feasible because you'll have to look at two fields for the same thing on the screen, one that looks good and another for input.
My text field was required.  What "fixed" this for me was removing the requirement of the text field, refreshing and trying again.  Then, even after enabling the requirement again, it still works.  Is your text field required?
This is a strange fix and it also could be this dev org I am using.  Another weird thing I'm noticing is that when I create a new field with read/write access, I'm unable to edit it from the page layout for a few minutes, even if I refresh.  Then after 5-10 minutes without making any system changes, I am able to edit the field.  Prior to that, the field is greyed out as if it is read-only.  This has occurred with more than one field on my custom object.
